# In D3.js How to draw a map with full screen width?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I created a `geo map`(world map).I try to stretch my map based on screen width.`svg` don't support `width:100%` so that i created a parent `div` `width:100%` for `svg`.

### Sample Code

```
<div id="world-placeholder" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
     // svg part goes here
</div>
```

Also, I tried `svg` attribute like `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio`.But Still i can't able to create.

I added my `fiddle link` below so kindly take a look and help me.

Fiddle Link - http://jsfiddle.net/acvefmhz/1/

Map is working fine.But i need show my map as a full screen(`Need to stretch full window`)

Comment: the problem is inside your javascript code where you set a fixed dimension for width and height

Comment: I tried with using parent width and height like $("svg").parent().width() and $("svg").parent().height();.Even though it is not working.If you can give me solution in fiddle.Thanks

Answer (score 6):

```
var width = window.innerWidth,
height = window.innerHeight;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/acvefmhz/4/

Comment: This is not responsive though